# Specify a relative path to 'php_value error_log'

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, error-handling

Rather than put the absolute path to an error_log in my .htaccess, I would like to find a way to specify it relative to the .htaccess file (or similar):

```
php_value error_log %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/libs/log/error/PHP_errors.log
```

It would be something like I would want to do, but this doesn't seem to work. If I specify the absolute, it does work.

Comment: What happens if you set it to `./path/error.log`?

Comment: @jexact genius! add it as an answer and i'll mark it as correct.

Comment: now i just need to figure out how to only log fatal errors.

Comment: Just change the error reporting level. Example: `php_value error_reporting 21` (equals to `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR)`) Here you can find other values: [PHP: Predefined Constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it to `./path/error.log`.

Comment: While this works, it's relative to the location of the currently executing php file. So if you run some code in other folders, then the location of the error log will move relative to that. IMO its not very useful in that case because most people will use some folders.

Comment: Excuse the necro, but O'Roony just saved me a lot of debugging time. I kept wondering why the heck my logs were appearing in the wrong folders. So definitely don't use the ./path method unless you've got all requests routed to an index.php file or something.

Answer (score 2):

When you have access to the server-config `httpd.conf` file, you can add the Line:

```
# set this to your document-root path
Define DOCROOT   "d:\htdocs"
```

and in your htaccess you can write:

```
php_value error_log ${DOCROOT}/libs/log/error/PHP_errors.log
```

With this define you can even replace all other places where your document root is use e.g.

```
DocumentRoot "${DOCROOT}"
```

@see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/de/mod/core.html#define